# MYSQL error 1062. How do I make a full row of data unique. and include an AUTO_INCREMENT?

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

I'm trying to make a table where no two rows are the same. In comma separated format, it would look like this:

```
1, Joe Smith, 123 Main Street, Seattle, WA, 98101
2, Jane Doe, 321 Main Street, Seattle, WA, 98101
3, Barry White, 111 A St., Los Angeles, CA, 90013
```

The goal: No two rows should have the same combo of `name,address,city,state,zip`. So there should be no other row with a Joe Smith who lives at 123 Main Street, Seattle WA 98101.

At the same time, I want an auto-incremented column `id`: That's the left-most column in each row.

Here's my `CREATE TABLE` code so far:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contributors`(
    id int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `name` varchar(255),
    address varchar(255),
    city varchar(255),
    state varchar(2),
    zip varchar(11),
    CONSTRAINT pk_Contributor PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT (id,`name`,address,city,state,zip)
);
```

The table gets created just fine, but when I run `INSERT` queries I get this error: `[Err] 1062 - Duplicate entry '1-----' for key 'PRIMARY'`

I'm pulling data from a table with rows that have multiple Joe Smith's with the same address, city, state and zip. Example:

```
Joe Smith, 123 Main Street, Seattle, WA, 98101
Joe Smith, 123 Main Street, Seattle, WA, 98101
```

How do I fix the error and make the table I want?

Comment: Make the *ID* a `PRIMARY KEY`, and the *name + address* an additional `UNIQUE KEY`. Don't make the primary key over all columns. It won't work with `AUTO INCREMENT` either.

Comment: You may want to look at [`IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html) keyword once you have the correct index created as you'll likely want to continue past those rows which you've already insert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a secondary UNIQUE constraint which does not include the id:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contributors`(
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(255),
    address varchar(255),
    city varchar(255),
    state varchar(2),
    zip varchar(11),
    UNIQUE KEY (name, address, city, state, zip)
);
```

Notes:

- This doesn't address alternate spellings of addresses, zip vs. zip+4, etc. You might not be able to prevent duplicate entries as easily as you think.
- The unique key, like any index, can be at most 1000 bytes long. If you use utf8 character set, you have to count 3 bytes per character. So your varchar(255) columns are too long to be combined into a multi-column index. There are good reasons besides this to choose shorter string columns.
- Don't put a DEFAULT on an AUTO_INCREMENT primary key.
- Keep in mind that because NULL is not equal to NULL, any row with at least one NULL is not the same as another row with the same non-null values. Example:

  ```
  mysql> select * from contributors;
  +----+-----------+-----------------+---------+-------+------+
  | id | name      | address         | city    | state | zip  |
  +----+-----------+-----------------+---------+-------+------+
  |  1 | Joe Smith | 123 Main Street | Seattle | WA    | NULL |
  |  2 | Joe Smith | 123 Main Street | Seattle | WA    | NULL |
  +----+-----------+-----------------+---------+-------+------+
  ```

  For this reason, you might want to make these columns NOT NULL

Comment: `[Err] 1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'name'`. There are many empty strings and `NULL`s in the table from which I'm pulling data to insert into my target table. (I edited my question to make that clearer).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Does that answer have any advantage over using `IGNORE`?

Comment: @Username, the `INSERT IGNORE` option is just so a conflict with a unique key doesn't result in an error. This comes up if you want to do a bulk-insert and you want all the rows that can succeed to do so without being canceled by the one row that conflicts.